# Check if a list of ids all exist in MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What is the most efficient way in `MySQL` and `PHP` to check if a list of ids all exist? I want the function return result to be `true` if **all** ids exists, else `false`.

I was thinking:

```
  $ids = array(2233, 5545, 9478, 5343, 3545);
  do_all_groups_exist($ids);

  function do_all_groups_exist(array $ids = array()) {
      if(empty($ids)) {
          return true;
      }

      $SQL = "SELECT count(`id`) as count
                FROM groups
               WHERE `id` IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ")";

      ...

      $row = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
      return (intval($row->count) === count($ids)) ? true : false;
 }
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: maybe i think  this code is fast in the line

Comment: Looks pretty good to me, presumably the `id` is indexed/primary key - so it should be the fastest way.

Comment: That is pretty much how I would have done it.

Comment: would this keep scanning the whole table even after the id's listed are found?

Comment: This assumes each id can exist only once

Comment: @RobbieAverill from list of ids, is there a way I can find any of id exists in table or not without using php ? :D

Comment: @Jigar if you have a new question you should ask it on its own :-) *hint* use the SQL in this question without PHP. Just check it returns more than zero

Answer (score 4):

You can get result in the sql statement itself

```
$countids= count($ids);

     $sql= "SELECT CASE WHEN (
                SELECT count(id) as cnt
                FROM groups
                WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $ids) . ") )=$countids

            THEN 'true'
            ELSE 'false'  END as result"
    ...

$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['result'];
```

You will get result from coloumn name 'result'

It will return true only when all ids exists in table.

Comment: May I know whether it is working or not for you? I have updated my code.