# 'AND' condition for (id array) in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an mysql table like this.

```
+----+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------+
| id | sku      | sellerID | name                                                                      | mode | created             |
+----+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------+
|  1 | Sample   |        1 | SampleItem                                                                |    1 | 2016-05-20 12:04:33 |
|  2 | Sample   |        2 | Sample1                                                                   |    1 | 2016-06-14 12:23:24 |
|  3 | SDGS046  |        1 | Shivaprasad                                                               |    2 | 2016-06-18 05:26:27 |
|  4 | PAWA006  |        1 | Panda Baby Walker Music                                                   |    2 | 2016-06-18 06:19:10 |
|  5 | PAWA005  |        1 | WonderKart Panda Walker for Kids (colour may vary)                        |    2 | 2016-06-18 06:24:23 |
|  6 | WKBR1301 |        1 | Planet of Toys New Born Toddler Protable Rocker                           |    2 | 2016-06-18 06:26:30 |
|  7 | PAKS001  |        1 | Panda Baby Musical Swing With Multiple Age Settings | 4 Stages | (Orange) |    2 | 2016-06-18 06:28:19 |
|  8 | WKGS046  |        1 | The Flyers Bay Flyer's Bay Ultra Durable Big Wheel Scooter (Silver)       |    2 | 2016-06-18 06:57:25 |
|  9 | MABS001  |        1 | Mastela Booster to Toddler 6M+ Seat (DarkGray)                            |    2 | 2016-06-20 06:25:00 |
| 10 | WKGS546  |        1 | Saffire Kids Scooter with Tractor Wheels Green                            |    2 | 2016-06-20 06:26:50 |
+----+----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------+
```

I want get data by query like.

```
SELECT * FROM `sku` WHERE `sellerID` = 1 AND id = 3 AND id = 4 AND id = 10;
```

but m trying this like

`SELECT * FROM sku WHERE sellerID = 1 AND id IN (3,4,10);`

it returns rows, if id(3,4,10) any available in table, but i want return row, if every id(3 and 4 and 10) available in table.

I want to pass an array to check `AND` Condition. Please suggest me if there is any solution available.

Comment: a similar thread here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290148/check-if-a-list-of-ids-all-exist-in-mysql-and-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would count the number of records in a subquery that matches the original `where` criteria and if that count is 3, then do the selection only:

```
SELECT * FROM sku
WHERE sellerID = 1
    AND id IN (3,4,10) 
    AND 3 = (SELECT count(*) FROM sku WHERE sellerID = 1 AND id IN (3,4,10));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation to count the matching rows for each seller:

```
SELECT sellerId
FROM `sku`
WHERE id IN (3, 4, 10)
GROUP BY sellerId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id) = 3;
```

If you want the original rows, you can use this query to bring in the appropriate rows for the matching `sellerId`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use all function to accomplish you requirement. But for that you should use subquery for the condition.

```
SELECT * FROM sku WHERE sellerID = 1 AND id=all (select sellerID  from sku where sellerID in (3,4,10));
```

or else if you are getting those values directly from some query then you can include the same in that as subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM sku WHERE sellerID = 1 AND id=all (select sellerID  from from_ur_table_for_codition);
```